# Expression to calculate # of time X appears per month

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

I'm brand new to Access/SQL and i'm hoping you won't mind a potentially stupid question, please let me know if I haven't detailed this enough.

I have data in the below format, and I need to determine how many times a Meter # appears each month i.e. even if the total repeats against every line (since each Meter # record will appear multiple times per month) thats fine as thats just how the current query works so I can evolve it from there.

[Table Format in Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPz7N.jpg)

I've seen a fair few other replies and some code seemed like it might work but I haven't been able to modify it to work in my case so please let me know if there is an example I've missed that I could use here.

I currently have an expression in order to calculate the month - simply

```
Month([dbo_tou_service_ord_read].[read_datetime])
```

but as my data is larger than what I can put into `Excel` (1.6M) rows I need to rework how I'd normally work this data. I'd normally determine the Month 1-12 and `pivot` the data and it would automatically give me the count for each record that I require but i'm unsure as to how to replicate this in Access or SQL.

My data only shows the most recent 4 months

Ideal results would be a expression or SQL that I could add into either `Access/Excel` that would result in another 4 Columns called Monthly Count 1-4 and each would Display the # of times the site appears, with the Column order being Oldest to Newest (Left to Right)

[Ideal Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPKpP.jpg)

Comment: Use the _Crosstab query_ wizard.

Comment: Thanks @Gustav, I've looked into that and figured it out. Cheers for the help.